# NetInfo.getConnectionInfo() return unknown for android

Tags: android, react-native

I am using the following code to get the connection info but it return unknown for android:

```
componentDidMount() {
NetInfo.getConnectionInfo().then(connectionInfo => {
    console.log("Connection type", connectionInfo.type);
    console.log("Connection effective type", connectionInfo.effectiveType);
});}
```

I'm using [react-native-netinfo](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo) package to get connection info.

React Native Version: 0.59.0

Comment: how u r importing  NetInfo.

Comment: import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo"

Comment: Please,  Try with the mobile internet connection on.